# Flutter: change theme brightess on part of screen?

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I make a theme get a Dark brightess on only a part of the screen? The brightness doest not work on the **text**.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Theme(
            data: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
            child: Container(
              child: Text("Bright Text"),
            ),
          ),
          Theme(
            data: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
            child: Container(
              child: Text("Dark Text"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: this does work though

Comment: I am have version 1.0 here and the text is not changing =/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this solution actually works, the reason you can't observe it in your original example is because the default text color in both color modes is the same — black (at least that's what I've got experimenting with it).

If you change your example to use a widget that uses a color that actually changes, you can clearly see it's working:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Theme(
            data: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
            child: Container(
              child: Icon(Icons.audiotrack), // always renders a black icon
          ),
          Theme(
            data: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
            child: Container(
              child: Icon(Icons.audiotrack), // always renders a white icon
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Sometimes you need to get the brightness of the current context to do some intricate configuration; the common way to do this: `MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness` will always give you the current color mode of the [device/platform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/platformBrightness.html).

If you want to get the brightness that was "overridden" by the method above, you need to use `Theme.of(context).brightness` instead.